# Unity Container in Metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, unity-container, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I am building a composite application for Microsoft tablet.
I wonder if it is possible to use UNITY container in Metro apps?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity 3.0 for Windows RT preview is available.
http://unity.codeplex.com/

Comment: Many thanks! Still in Alpha version though, did you have the chance to test it out? If so, did you notice any issues?